# Choosing the top five cells in Excel

Tags: excel, match, rank

I have an Excel spreadsheet that look like this:

```
        School A  School B  School C
Latin   2%        1%        3%
Spanish 50%       60%       45%
French  25%       15%       20%
Italian 15%       20%       25%
German  8%        4%        7%
```

On a separate tab, I'd like to generate a report that states the language preferences for each school from largest to smallest.  Although it isn't shown, I have 34 schools that I'm working with.  I'd like the separate tab to look like the following:

```
Top 5 Languages at School A
1.  Language A             % Lang. A Speakers
2.  Language B             % Lang. B Speakers  
3.  Language C             % Lang. C Speakers
4.  Language D             % Lang. D Speakers
5.  Language E             % Lang. E Speakers


Top 5 Languages at School B
1.  Language A             % Lang. A Speakers
2.  Language B             % Lang. B Speakers  
3.  Language C             % Lang. C Speakers
4.  Language D             % Lang. D Speakers
5.  Language E             % Lang. E Speakers


Top 5 Languages at School C
1.  Language A             % Lang. A Speakers
2.  Language B             % Lang. B Speakers  
3.  Language C             % Lang. C Speakers
4.  Language D             % Lang. D Speakers
5.  Language E             % Lang. E Speakers
```

Comment: The title of this question makes it look like you're looking for just the top 5. Are there more than 5 languages? Could you give a sample of what you would like the separate tab to look like given the sample data you gave above?

Comment: Sorry, there are actually 70 languages, but I tried to simplify it to make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your other sheet has the school headers in row 1, and in the same order as the original data - then you could put this in A2 and drag across and down as required:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(LARGE(Sheet1!B:B,ROW()-1),Sheet1!B:B,0))
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a tie. It will choose one language twice and leave the other out.